# Seed method does not add user while migrating with "-" in name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

*Please read the paragraph EDIT2 for the actual state of the question*

I am trying to add an initial account to my database while a migration is running, to ensure access to my application.

Unfortunatly the table `AspNetUsers` is not changed after the `Seed` method is finished and I can't find a proper way to debug for possible errors.

**Configuration.cs**

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        ContextKey = "Namespace.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
    }

    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
             new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(
                 new ApplicationDbContext()));

        var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "admin",
            Email = "admin@admin",
            LastName ="lname",
            FirstName = "fname"
        };

        manager.Create(user, @"gibberish");
        /* context.SaveChanges(); ?valid */
    }
}
```

After issuing the `update-database -force -verbose` command the pm console writes `The Seed method is being executed` (free translation from German), but as stated above the table is not updated with a new user.

Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT:**
I just tried the following:

```
if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Administrator"))
{
    var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
    var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
    var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Administrator" };
    manager.Create(role);
}
```

which did work. So a role named Administrator has been created after `Update-Database -Force` was issued. The user however, not.

**EDIT2:**
So apparently I found the culprit. 
I was trying to make sure that an admin account was always available. Therefor I tried to add a user `username-admin`. However this did not work. After some time I thought about trying it with a different approach and changed the username to `username`. Now this did the trick and the user was added and pushed into the role `Administrator`.

The question remains: why does it not work adding a user with a special character like `-`?

Comment: You are passing `new ApplicationDbContext()` to `UserStore` contructor instead on context instance you have already got in parameters, it might be a problem, because your last commented line will not do anything in this case.

Comment: it makes no difference in the outcome, if I use `new ApplicationDbcontext()` or `context` plus `context.SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `UserName` can only be alphanumeric, i.e. not even an email address is allowed. You need to turn off the validation or implement your own validator (as easily found on SO), e.g.

```
_userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(_userStore);
_userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<IdentityUser>(_userManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
```

Comment: Thank you alot Besrl. Googling for `AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false` brought some more insights!